# Why Firebase and Google Analytics metrics doesn't match?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I integrated both GA and Firebase to my app and I'm having confusing analytics metrics specifically Active user and total session.

**Firebase:**
[image: Firebase Dashboard]
**GA:** As you can see the count doubled on GA.
[image: Firebase Dashboard imported to GA]

**Firebase:** Session 19K, Active user: 9.7K
[image: Last 7 days Firebase metrics]

**GA:** Active user: 13K *(3.3K off)*, Session: 53K *(34K off)*
[image: Last 7 days GA metrics]

As you can see **Total session** and **Active user**  do not match at all on the same period of time. This is so confusing as these metrics are extremely important for marketing.

I'm wondering if anyone had a similar issue? Could I be doing anything wrong ?

SDKs versions used:
`FirebaseAnalytics (= 4.2.0), FirebaseCore (= 4.0.20) 
and GoogleAnalytics (3.17.0)`

Comment: I didn't got an answer from Google, I'll appreciate it if this was up voted!

Answer (score 1):

Definition of a session is different between Firebase and Google Analytics.

- Google Analytics: a single hit will initiate a session. [More info](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2731565)
- Firebase: Firebase records the first hit but don't start a session until the user has interacted with the page for 10s (by default). [More info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41030377/how-does-firebase-analytics-define-a-session)

Comment: Interesting to know, but does this explain the 34K sessions and 3.3K users count difference ? Even if we accept that 65% of the session where mistakes and the users opened the app for less than 10 sec, it still doesn't explain the user count difference.

Comment: 65% more sessions in GA does not at all sound unreasonable, our difference is even bigger. It simply comes down to how they define sessions, like Eduardo said.

Comment: Try to segment out your bounced sessions in GA. The number still are not likely to match but it's a more fair comparison.

Comment: Alright, Thanks, what about the Active Users count difference? PS: These are App analytics not website, unlike websites user tracking on mobile should be accurate and bounce rate shouldn't be as high as on websites...

Comment: I always assumed that if a user engages with the app for less than 10 seconds it is not counted as an active user in Firebase. Which makes sense to me, since they haven't really used the app. I'm not a 100% on this though.